# Запрет отсутствия файлов в репозитории при push (Git Hook)

Tags: git

Есть некий репозиторий, в нем лежат два файла (app/config.sample и app/routes.sample)
Подскажите как составить хук, который не даст закомитить изменения при отсутсвии этих файлов в репозитории

Answer (score 2):

У гита есть такая функция, которая называется [Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Вам нужен `pre-commit`

Содержание примерно такое:

```
git diff --cached --name-status | while read st file; do
    if [ "$st" == 'D' & ("$file" = "app/config.sample" | "$file" = "app/routes.sample")]; then 
        echo "Ваше сообщение о ошибке"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: по-моему, условие, приведённое в вашем примере, содержит синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вполне может быть, писал код прям тут :)

Comment: так может быть, настало время найти и исправить (возможные) ошибки? здесь это никогда не поздно сделать.